# Automatically sign powershell script using Get-PfxCertificate

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have to sign remote scripts with a certificate from the remote machine from which I have a `.pfx` file.

I would like to automate the scripting by supplying the password to the `Get-PfxCertificate` programmatically.

So the question is:

Is it possible to somehow supply programmatically the required password to

`Get-PfxCertificate`?

Answer (score 9):

```
$CertPath = "my.pfx"
$CertPass = "mypw"
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertPath, $CertPass)
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $Cert -TimeStampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll -FilePath $OutputFilename
```

Make sure you have the proper permissions otherwise you won't be able to create an instance of the X509Certificate2 object.

Comment: Great answer. You can use Get-PfxData for this, as well. You need to supply the password as a SecureString and the EndEntityCertificates to use the certificate without being prompted. Using your example:

`  $SecurePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypw" -AsPlainText -Force;
  $PfxData=Get-PfxData -FilePath "my.pfx" -Password $SecurePassword;
  Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $PfxData.EndEntityCertificates[0] -TimeStampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll -FilePath $OutputFilename;
`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is by loading your certificate directly from your certificate store using PS Providers. Use **Get-PSProviders** to determine available PSProviders on your machine.
Once you have cert provider loaded, you can now get the certificate using Get-ChildItem

Launch ***certmgr.msc*** from run to launch the certificate store
Assuming that your certificate is stored under *Personal* folder in your cert store 
 and has "**Company Name**" set in the subject property of the certificate, and there is only certificate in that folder with *Company Name* in the subject - you can get the certificate like so

```
$my_cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? {$_.Subject -match "Company Name"}
```

$my_cert will be your certificate object that you can pass directly to **Set-AuthenticodeSignature** cmdlet

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $my_cert -FilePath fqn_to_dll.dll -Timestampserver "http://timestampurl"
```

post signing, you can retrieve the sign status by querying on the *Status* property for "Valid" or not like

```
$result = Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $my_cert -FilePath fqn_to_dll.dll -Timestampserver "http://timestampurl" | Select Status
if(-Not ($result -eq "Valid")){
    Write-Output "Error Signing file: Status: $($result.Status)"    
}
```

Comment: Nice option, but how does this avoid the password prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of checking around on this and couldn't find a clean way to provide the password programmatically.  I suspect it is meant to be this way for security reasons.  Either that or the PowerShell development team just blew it by not including a Credential parameter for this cmdlet.  The only other option I can think of is to use someting like SendKeys to send the individual password character key presses to the PowerShell console at the right time via a background job (blech - just threw up in my mouth a little).  :-)

Comment: Starting with PowerShell 6, Get-PfxCertificate will allow you to pass it a -Password parameter (which needs to be passed as a SecureString object): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate?view=powershell-6